# Computational tasks resulting from Chern-Weil theory

Tags: computational-geometry, chern-classes, computational-topology

I have recently learned Chern-Weil theory for smooth and complex manifolds, as well as surrounding material on cohomology with integral coefficients.

I am curious what computational tasks are associated to the theory. Much like the insight of Euclidian domains allows for an algorithm (the Euclidian algorithm) for the computation of the greatest common denominator gcd(n,m), along with two numbers a and b such that an + bm = gcd(n,m), I want to know if there is a computational task associated to Chern-Weil theory which would "sum up" the fruits of an implementation, e.g. in magma.

Maybe this would mean coming up with a notion of "presentation"; a presentation would be a description of a bundle which arose from generators and relations somehow. Then I thought of making the computational task the computation of the Chern classes of a particular bundle given a presentation.

In the above, I am hoping for something "algebraic", similar to the notion of a finitely presented complex affine variety expressed using finitely many polynomial equations in finitely many variables or a finitely presented projective variety expressed using finitely man homogeneous equations. Is it possible that using power series instead would produce a notion of presentation for smooth manifolds?

Certainly I would want the notion of presentation to feature $\mathbb{N}$ (whether in terms of number of equations, number of variables, number of homogeneous equations, etc.). Besides calculating various cohomology classes, I am keen to hear about other "generic" tasks, potentially computational and associated to knowledge the Chern classes, or potentially associated to a connection instead.

Overall I was hoping that several algorithms based on presentations of bundles, perhaps first for the case of finitely presented affine and projective complex varieties (not necessarily smooth?) would have tasks associated to them which would terminate, and others (witnessing a sequence of codimension 1 subvarieties or detecting whether smooth choices for this are possible?).